# sizeof() behaviour in C programming

Tags: c, sizeof, implicit-conversion, string-literals

This is my program..

```
int main(void) {

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(""));

    // first if else statement
    if(1 > -2) printf("Yes");
    else printf("No");

    printf("\n");

    // second if else statement    
    if( sizeof("") > -2) printf("Yes");
    else printf("No");
}
```

In first printf() why it's printing 1 as output,though I've passed an empty string?
In first if-else statement I got the correct output -> Yes as expected, but in second if-else statement It prints the outout -> No, Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

My output is..
1
Yes
No

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `sizeof` returns `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. The equivalent of `if (sizeof("") > -2)` would be `if (1LU > -2)`. The answers explain why this is false.

Comment: If you want the length of a string (`0` for `""`), use `strlen`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All strings in C end in a `\0` null character. This signifies the sting end.

When programming in C its always good to visualize how the data is actually stored in memory, as you can see here, "Hello" is 5 characters long, however 6 characters must be given to the char array to leave space for this null character.

[image: Sting memory representaion in C]

Heres what your example looks like as suggested by Bob Jarvis:

[image]

As for the `sizeof("") > -2` being false, have a look at sepp2k's answer

Comment: Nice visualization. I think it would be helpful to OP and others new to C if you included a visualization of an empty string as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof("")` is one because string literals represent character arrays that contain the given characters *followed by '\0'*. So `""` represents the character array `{'\0'}`.

`sizeof("") > -2` is false because `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type. The comparison causes `-2` to be converted to `size_t`, which causes it to wrap around and become a number much larger than one.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @sepp2k's explanation of why `sizeof("") < -2` is true, here's a modified version of your program which shows the results clearly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(""));

    // first if else statement
    if(1 > -2) printf("Yes");
    else printf("No");

    printf("\n");

    // second if else statement    
    if( sizeof("") > -2) printf("Yes");
    else printf("No");

    printf("\n");

    // third if else statement    
    if((long int)sizeof("") > -2) printf("Yes\n");
    else printf("No\n");

    printf("sizeof(\"\") = %lu  -2 = %d  -2 = %u\n", sizeof(""), -2, (unsigned int)-2);
}
```

This outputs

```
1
Yes
No
Yes
sizeof("") = 1  -2 = -2  -2 = 4294967294
```

As you can see, when -2 is treated as an `unsigned int` it becomes a very large number. To understand why this is you might want to study and understand the two's-complement representation of negative numbers.

Comment: Despite the common habit to pick up the OP where shes is, I'd rather like to see well formatted source code. Be a good example, people learn from you!

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (5.2.1 Character sets):

> 2. ... **A byte with all bits set to 0**, called the null character, shall exist in
>    the basic execution character set; it **is used to terminate a character string**.

and (6.4.5 String literals):

> 6 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
> each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
> or literals.78) **The multibyte character sequence is then used to
> initialize an array of static storage duration and length just
> sufficient to contain the sequence.**

So each string literal is stored as a character array with static storage duration including the terminating zero.

The empty string literal `""` is stored like:

```
char empty_literal[] = { '\0' };
```

and has the type `char[1]`. Hence the operator sizeof for this literal (character array) will yield the value `1` of the type `size_t` that is an unsigned integer type.

When a binary operation is evaluated the compiler at first determines their common type. For example in the condition of the if statement:

```
if(1 > -2) printf("Yes");
```

there is used the relational operator >. According to the C Standard (6.5.8 Relational operators):

> 3 If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic
> conversions are performed.

As in the condition the both operands `1` and `-2` have the type `int` then the common type of the operands is integer and naturally 1 is greater than -2.

In the condition of this if statement:

```
if( sizeof("") > -2) printf("Yes");
```

the first operand has the type `size_t` while the second operand has the type int. The rank of the type size_t is greater than the rank of the type int so the second operand is converted to the type size_t by propagating the sign bit and the result representation is considered as a representation of unsigned value.

Even if the type `size_t` had the same conversion rank as the type `int` nevertheless according to the rules of the  usual arithmetic conversions the object of the signed type `int` was converted to the type `unsigned int`.

From the C Standard (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions):

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type.

Here is a demonstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int x = 0;
    signed int y = -1;
    
    printf( "x + y > 0 is %s\n", x + y > 0 ? "true" : "false" );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is:

```
x + y > 0 is true
```